# Subdomain not working (Ubuntu 16.04 & Apache)

Tags: apache, ubuntu, apache2, subdomain

I've been looking everywhere for a long time and i just can't figure it out.. I'm trying to create a subdomain called bikestore which is part of example.com, (bikestore.example.com) - i've added this code to etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName bikestore.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/bikestore.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

i've also added this line in /etc/hosts:

> (server ip) bikestore.example.com

and create a new directory (/var/www/bikestore.example.com)

i've restarted apache but i can't access bikestore.example.com, i'm using Cloudflare for my domain also. Do you see if i've done something wrong? I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and Apache

Answer (score 0):

You have to create file *bikestore.example.com.conf* in subdirectory *sites-available* like 
/etc/apache2/sites-available/bikestore.example.com.conf

The file should contain more than just code you posted.

```html
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName bikestore.example.com
     DocumentRoot /var/www/bikestore.example.com

   <Directory /var/www/bikestore.example.com>
     # directory settings sample
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
     AllowOverride None
 </Directory>

 # Protect files and directories from prying eyes.
 <FilesMatch "(\.(engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl)|code-style\.pl|Entries.*| #Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$">
          Order allow,deny
 </FilesMatch>

 # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
 # alert, emerg.
 LogLevel crit
 ErrorLog  ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/bikestore.example.com.error.log

 # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
 # alert, emerg.
 CustomLog  ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/bikestore.example.com.access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

You should also consider some security in this config.

After you've done that you enable site and reload apache settings with:

> sudo a2ensite bikestore.example.com
>
> sudo service apache2 reload

This will create a link to your config file in directory sites-enabled

After that you reload apache and if everything goes well, site will work., but if not, you'll find error in your error folder /var/log/apache2

Do check this tutorials:
https://www.ostechnix.com/configure-apache-virtual-hosts-ubuntu-part-1/

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Hey, when i do sudo a2ensite bikestore.example.com it says: Site bikestore.example.com does not exist!

Comment: You have to configure it in your domain DNS settings as CNAME that points to url or A record that points to an ip address (then you have to configure a port 80 forwarding to your computer on your router)